# Example of a finite non-associative field which does not satisfy the cancellation law

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Is there a finite structure $(F;+,-,*,0,1)$ that satisfies all the axioms for fields except the associative law for multiplication, and moreover does not satisfy the cancellation law: $(a \neq 0 \land a*b = a*c) \rightarrow b=c$? Note, I want $F$ to satisfy the commutative law for multiplication.

Comment: I don't have an answer but here are two observations: by the Zorn Artin theorem the multiplication cannot be alternative since that would imply it's a field ( $x(xy)=(xx)y$ and $(xy)y=x(yy)$). Secondly one cannot have that the underlying additive group is cyclic and that the unit is a generator since the existence of an inverse for non zero elements implies the group homomorphism $a\cdot:(F,+)\rightarrow (F,+)$ would have to have the unit in it's image and so would be an isomorphism and therefore the cancellation law will hold.

Comment: Actually you can go further the underlying group cannot be cyclic since either $1$ is a generator or some $a\neq 0$ is a generator but in such case $a\cdot$ would send $1$ to $a$ which is not possible since $1$ has smaller order than $a$.

Answer (score 1):

On the group $M_2(\Bbb{C})$,  $$a*b = \frac12 (ab+ba)$$ where $ab$ is the matrix multiplication.

It is commutative and distributive over $+$, it has the identity matrix as neutral element and $0$ is absorbent, it is not associative nor cancellative.

Though it lacks the inverse axiom "for all $a$ there is $b$ such that $a*b=I$"

Comment: For reference, this is called a Jordan algebra. See e.g. [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_algebra).

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is my attempt. Take as the additive group $\mathbb{Z}/(2)^3$ and we set $1=(1,0,0)$ to be the unit. For simplicity $a=(0,1,0)$  $b=(0,0,1)$ and $c=(0,1,1)$. We now require the following identities $a^2=b^2=0$ and $a\cdot b=1$. From this one has $c=(a+b)$ so $c\cdot b=1$. We clearly do not have unique inverses but any such ring cannot have unique inverses. Also it follows that $(1+a)^2=(1+b)^2=(1+c)^2=1$ so every element has an inverse which covers all the non zero elements. It is also power associative but not alternating.